# How to compile and link OpenCL using GCC with the NVIDIA Toolkit on Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, opencl

I have the NVIDIA GPU computing toolkit installed at E:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\, I trying to compile opencl example program with:

```
gcc hello.c -I "E:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -L "E:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\lib\Win32" -lOpenCL -o hello.exe
```

And I have linker error:

```
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x142):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clGetPlatformIDs@12'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x179):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clGetDeviceIDs@24'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x1b1):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clCreateContext@24'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x1e0):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clCreateCommandQueue@20'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x218):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clCreateBuffer@24'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x24c):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clCreateProgramWithSource@20'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x284):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clBuildProgram@24'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x2a4):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clCreateKernel@12'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x2cc):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clSetKernelArg@16'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x2fc):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clEnqueueTask@20'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x34e):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clEnqueueReadBuffer@36'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x36d):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clFlush@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x37e):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clFinish@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x38f):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clReleaseKernel@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x3a0):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clReleaseProgram@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x3b1):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clReleaseMemObject@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x3c2):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clReleaseCommandQueue@4'
E:\Users\Lammar\AppData\Local\Temp/cc0Kbaaa.o(.text+0x3d3):hello.c: undefined re
ference to `clReleaseContext@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Whats wrong with it? How to get it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some related questions I install mingw-utils, then use `dlltool -l libOpenCL.a -d OpenCL.def -A -k` on http://pastebin.com/f2ac38b2f and compile it with: `gcc hello.c -I "E:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -lOpenCL -o hello.exe`. Now it compiles and works normally.